# How to write a function to display a character in Assembly Language using NASM?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I already have had a function which has two inputs `string` and `stringlength` named writeStr that will display on screen the `string`, here is the code:

```
writeStr:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp,esp
    mov     edx,[ebp+8]
    mov     ecx,[ebp+12]
    mov     ebx,1
    mov     eax,4
    int     80h
    leave
    ret
```

Now what I want is to write another function which has 1 input is a single character named `writeChar` then it will display that character on the screen. However, I also want to reuse the function `writeStr` for function `writeChar`, so how can i do that?

Comment: LEA instead of MOV, and a fixed size of 1.  Or if you really want to call `writeStr`, then push `1` for the size and a pointer to your `char` arg.

Comment: I know i can reuse `writeStr` by the way you tell me #Peter Cordes, but it's not what I really want. I want to write a new function which have only one input is a character and in code section it will reuse `writeStr`.

Comment: So you want to make a function with *similar* code to `writeStr`, not actually call it?  That's not what "reuse" normally means in software engineering; that's just copying and changing code to make a new function.  Anyway, that's the best option in this case, and what I was talking about in the first sentence of my first comment.  Your char arg will already be in memory on the stack when your function is called, so put a pointer to that into ECX.

Comment: I got it! Thanks for your assistance.